# pandas how to add a column of one dataframe as a row into another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following `df_1`,

```
 0      1        2        3
-1    201704   201705   201706
750     -1       -1       -1
760     12        0        0
```

I have another two DataFrames `df_2`,

```
code    avg_days
750       12
760       9.6
```

and `df_3`,

```
year_month    avg_days
 201704        13.5
 201705        14.5
 201706        15.5
```

I like to first add a row of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` into `df_1` and pad `df_2['avg_days']` with two `0`s, to make it look like `[0, 0, 12, 9.6]` and then insert it into column `1` of `df_1`, which will look like,

```
 0    1      2        3        4
-1    0   201704   201705   201706
 0    0      0        0        0
750   12    -1       -1       -1
760   9.6   12        0        0
```

finally, I want to pad `df_3['avg_days']` with two `0`s to make it look like `[0, 0, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5]` and then insert it as the 2nd row of `df_1`, which will look like,

```
 0    1      2        3        4
-1    0   201704   201705   201706
 0    0    13.5     14.5     15.5
750   12    -1       -1       -1
760   9.6   12        0        0
```

Comment: Your `code` column should be your index, would make your life 100% easier. Last step'd messy no matter what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data lacks structure: your desired result has no meaningful row and index labels. Consequently, the solution is also messy:

```
# merge df1 with df3
mrg = df1.T.merge(df3.rename(columns={'year_month': 0}), how='outer')

# realign column order
mrg.columns = np.arange(mrg.shape[1])
mrg.insert(1, 3, mrg.pop(3))

# merge result with df2
res = mrg.T.merge(df2.rename(columns={'code': 0}), how='outer')

# realign column order and names
res.insert(1, 4, res.pop('avg_days'))
res = res.fillna(0)
res.columns = np.arange(res.shape[1])

print(res)

       0     1         2         3         4
0   -1.0   0.0  201704.0  201705.0  201706.0
1    0.0   0.0      13.5      14.5      15.5
2  750.0  12.0      -1.0      -1.0      -1.0
3  760.0   9.6      12.0       0.0       0.0
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the lack of structure. Many are not aware of the concept of index (primary key) when working with data.

Comment: @ayorgo, Yep, I think we see this frequently with people moving from Excel (or, very occasionally, NumPy) to Pandas. No substitute for reading the docs here.

Comment: was going to use a slightly less messy solution, but could not figure out how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742695/pandas-how-to-use-pivot-table-to-aggregate-dataframe-for-averages

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you read up on Pandas Dataframes and how/why you would use 
indexing and slicing of these Dataframes. Your question (e.g. padding of zeros) 
suggests that you might need some help thinking about what setting values in a 
dataframe would do. As has been said, it is also a lot more useful if you keep 
track of what the meanings of the columns and indices are. Here is an 
alternative solution:

```
# your data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1:[201704.0,-1,12],2:[201705.0,-1,0],3:[201706.0,-1,0]}, 
index= [-1,750,760])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [750,760], 'avg_days':[12,9.6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'year_month':[201704.0,201705.0,201706.0],'avg_days' 
[13.5,14.5,15.5]})

# add the rows
df1.loc[0] = np.zeros(df1.shape[1])

# set the indexes in your dataframe (I set name to None as I don't know what 
# you want)
df2.set_index('code', inplace=True)
df2.index.set_names([None], inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'avg_days': 0}, inplace=True)

# add the df2 data to df1
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# again I am not sure what the columns mean in df1/result so I'll just use 
# apply here
month_to_avg_days_map = {k:v for k,v in df3.values}

def insert_value(col):
   month_year = col.loc[-1]
   if month_year in month_to_avg_days_map:
      return month_to_avg_days_map[month_year]
   return np.nan

result.loc[0,:] = result.apply(insert_value, axis=0)
result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

The result is as desired.